# Query against a view under master database is much slower than query directly under specific database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I am not sure whether there exists a general answer before I give more details.

For exmaple: I have a view named `vw_View`

I tried the following two queries to get the result:

1. **Under master database** `select * From [test].[dbo].[vw_View]`
2. **Under test database**  `select * From [dbo].[vw_View]`

Could anyone tell me why query against the same query but from `master` database is much slower than query against from the other databases, I even tried the others by:

```
Use [db]    --any other databases not master database
select * From [test].[dbo].[vw_View]
```

I have checked the actual execution plan, the join order differs but why it will change since I have already specify `[test].[dbo].[vw_View]` when under `master`

Just out of curiosity, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe that plan is coming from cache, and something was different when it was cached. Do you still get different plan if you use `with recompile`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but problem remains :(

Answer (score 3):

Have the same issue - executing a view from `master` goes infinitely long, but executing the same view "under any other user database on this server" goes only 8 sec.
I have an environment where we just migrated to SQL Server 2017 and "all other databases" have Compatibility Level = 2008 (or 2012)

So I did a few tests:

1. If I create a new DB with default Compatibility Level = 2017 and run the query it executes infinitely long
2. If I change Compatibility Level to 2008 and reconnect - 8 sec
3. If I change Compatibility Level back to 2017 - long run again

And the final thing we have noticed about the query itself - the query is using `CHARINDEX` function and if I comment it out the query executes equally 8 sec for both compatibility levels.

So... it looks like we have an mixed issue with `CHARINDEX` function execution on legacy database under Compatibility Level = 2017 context.

The solution is (if you can call it this way...) - to execute legacy queries under (the same) legacy execution context.

Answer (score 2):

*Note* this might not be the answer but it was too much text for a comment anyway...

One thing that we hear about a lot is when the developers complain about a slow running procedure which only runs slow when called from the application but runs fine when executing from the SSMS.

More often than not it is due to the different execution settings depending on from where the procedure is being called. To check if there is a difference in those setting I usually use SQL Profiler.

In your case you can open two different windows in the SSMS one in the context of `Master` database and the other in the context of the `User Database` and run SQL Profiler, the very first event profiler will capture, will be the `Event Class = Existing Connections` and `Text Data = -- network protocol: LPC.....`.

This record will show you all the default settings for each session where your are executing the commands, The settings would look something like....

```
-- network protocol: LPC
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

Now compare the settings of both sessions and see what are the differences.

The profiler also has a column `SIPD` which will help you to identify which window is which. I am pretty sure the answer is around somewhere there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I ran those two in the same session within the same scope